# What is the meaning of pulling a pin HIGH (of an IC)?

Tags: microcontroller, protocol, i2s

Let's say I have a microcontroller (ESP8266) driving a DAC via a I2S protocol. So the ESP is connected with 3 pins to the DAC, and sending the data to it throught these pins. But I wonder, how exactly is the data sent? From what I know, the pins are pulled either HIGH or LOW, but I wonder what exactly does it mean? Does HIGH and LOW refer to voltage? If so - since voltage is always a measure between two points, I don't understand what does it mean to pull the pins HIGH or LOW. HIGH and LOW with respect to what?

Comment: With respect to the microcontroller's ground.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. So LOW is same potential as ground? 2. So what if the voltages of the ICs are different? In my case, the ESP8266 runs with 3.3V and the DAC with 5V. What if I wanted to use a DAC that works with 12V for example?

Comment: Then you need a DAC which can work with 3.3V logic levels regardless of supply voltage, or if it can't, you need to level convert the 3.3V logic levels to something the DAC accepts as input.

Comment: @YoavKlein 1. Not necessarily. It's anything sufficiently close to ground. Usually a few hundred millivolts above ground will still count as low. Look at the Vil spec. 2. You probably need a level translator in that situation.

Comment: HI or “1” is  defined always in the datasheet of the receiving chip as Vih min. If this is not <3.3V then you need a level shifter.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't understand what does it mean to pull the pins HIGH or LOW.

Just for clarity - that is shorthand for a pin being pulled to a voltage which meets the requirements for a *logic level* High or a *logic level* Low.

The exact voltages which meet the limits for \$V_{ih}\$ (minimum voltage guaranteed to be recognized as logic level High) and \$V_{il}\$ (maximum voltage guaranteed to still be recognized as logic level Low) depend on the ICs involved.

> HIGH and LOW with respect to what?

In your case, that means with respect to the ground shared between the power source, microcontroller and DAC.

Comment: When you say "ground" you mean the lower between the two terminals?

Comment: No, "ground" is the reference point, which is marked at its respective pin. As the answerer wrote in the last paragraph.

Comment: @YoavKlein - Hi, Regarding: "*When you say "ground" you mean the lower between the two terminals?*" If the kind reply from *the busybee* isn't clear enough, then I recommend you provide a link to an image of your schematic, which we can then refer to.